# Presence and absence of `printk` function call determining the writing of data to a file using `filp_write` in a custom system call

Tags: c, file-io, linux-kernel, system-calls

First, let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I want to copy a file using a custom system call. Files to be copied are of the form:

```
$ cat abc.txt
1
2
343
5654
34
57
675
4534
575
23
54
76
```

And what I want to do using the syscall is to copy the file, number by number (because I want to use it for `cpuset` job migration, so need to write to destination file in the granularity of a number at a time, representing `pid`s).

For that I wrote the following helper function, to be called by my system call:

```c
int copy_file(char* dest_filename, char* source_filename){
    struct file *dest = filp_open(dest_filename, O_RDWR, 0);
    struct file *src  = filp_open(source_filename, O_RDWR, 0);

    char buf[100];
    long long dest_offset = 0;
    long long src_offset = 0;
    while (1){

        int count = 0;
        int ch;
        int flag = 1;
        while(1){
            flag = kernel_read(src, &ch, 1, &src_offset);
            if (!flag)
                break;
            buf[count++]=ch;
            if (ch == '\n')
                break;
        }
         if (!flag)
            break;
        printk("\n");  // <------------------------------ REGION TO FOCUS ON
        kernel_write(dest, buf, count, &dest_offset);
    }
    filp_close(src, NULL);
    filp_close(dest, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem which I am facing is as follows. If I remove the `printk` function call highlighted above, nothing is written to the destination file. While, if I incorporate the mentioned `printk` function call, to my astonishment, the write to the destination file takes place.

I am new to kernel programming. Is some timing issue going on? Please can anyone guide me?

Comment: `filp_open` has an interesting `man` page: _"This is the helper to open a file from kernelspace if you really have to. But in generally you should not do this, so please move along, nothing to see here.."_ :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo , but I _really have to_ :(

Comment: Why would you want to write to a file from kernel? Consider creating a /dev device where userspace service reads and writes to a file, it's _way_ simpler.

Comment: Where do you test whether open succeeds?

Comment: @KamilCuk well, part of a use-case, trying to abstract the entire isolation subsystem through a single system call, making things transparent to a user.

Comment: @stark could failed open really be the case? Still let me check...

Comment: @stark I tried checking the file structures returned using `IS_ERR`, and no error is reported even when there is no copy...

Comment: In most cases, If adding a `printk` call changes a behavior, then the module contains **undefined behavior**. E.g. with `kernel_read` you read a single **byte**, but store it into the **integer** `ch`. That is, 3 bytes of 4 inside `ch` are *trash*. And you compare all its bytes with `if (ch == '\n')`.